# nginx conditional rewrite issue

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args =404;

    rewrite ^/(\w+)$ /?system=$1 break;
}
```

This block rewrites `/first` to `/?system=first`, `/second` to `/?system=second`, etc.

However, this rewrite should not be done for `/six` and `/nine`. How could I write this condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed with regex

```
rewrite ^/((?!six|nine)\b\w+$) /?system=$1 break;
```

Comment: You can skip the first "\b" behind "nine".

Comment: @qräbnö Thanks! The another problem is that I want to rewrite  only if the mentioned string goes first. For example, I don't want to rewrite /something/`second`

Comment: You do `^/` already at the beginning and no `/` at end. So `/something/second` won't be matched!?

Comment: @qräbnö Removed first \b. Thanks